# Intellij not showing Activity deprecated methods

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Idea to develop Android (not Android Studio), and can't find a way to mark deprecated methods either on Code Analysis or on the Make console.

For example, Activity.onCreateDialog(int id) is clearly deprecated since API Level 13, and project min/target API level is 14, but no mark is added nor notified on console when building.

[image]

Locally created methods (as in, created in the project) are marked just fine.

Intellij version: CE 12.1.4

Thanks

Comment: Click File->Settings.  Type "deprecated" in the search box.  Do you have the lint options enabled?

Comment: Android Lint is enabled, although I don't see any "deprecated" option below "Android Lint" category (I DO see it under "General/Deprecated API Usage". In any case, is not that.

Answer (score -2):

If I'm understanding correctly annotating it with `@Deprecated` should work.